# How can I find the size of an NSURLRequest's header?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8.4

I'm trying to figure out how much network traffic my application generates and receives. I know how to find the size of the message body, but I'm not sure how to size the header. How do I do this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Transfer_Size_Constant

Comment: That constant indicates the size is undetermined.